# how to make this into a recursion?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I am trying to make the `value` loop over the cash but all my attempts failed am sure this needs recursion but I just can't seem to apply it correctly.

```
r = {"pound":1.00,"cent":0.01,"quarter":.25,"five":5.00}
m = []
for a in r:
    m.append(r[a])
m = sorted(m, reverse=True)

def exchange(cash):
    c = []
    for value in m:
        if value > cash:
            break
        if value <= cash:
            c.append(value)
            cash = cash - value
        return cash
```

Main problem is that it usually just goes through the four `value`s and thats it and I am trying to make it repeat itself at higher `value`s until  `value>cash`

My first idea was to put this below the last if

```
if value <= cash:
    c.append(value)
    cash = exchange(cash -value)
```

but didnt work as planned

cash :`print exchange(20.0)` , `print exchange(3.0)`

The main aim is to calculate the types of banknotes, which I am attempting with `c`

final result should be `0` but I get at the moment `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can use recursion for your implementation, by passing only the remainder from the current `cash` divided by the closest `value` to the next recursion:

```
r = {"pound":1.00,"cent":0.01,"quarter":.25,"five":5.00}
m = sorted(r.items(), key=lambda t: -t[1])
def exchange(cash):
    for name, value in m:
        if value <= cash:
            return dict([(name, int(cash / value))] + exchange(cash % value).items())
    else:
        return {}
print exchange(21.8)
```

This outputs:

```
{'pound': 1, 'quarter': 3, 'five': 4, 'cent': 5}
```